# Unable to get disconnected groups to align on the same X axis.

Tags: javascript, vis.js

I am currently using vis.js to model workflows.  With the new version (4.16.1) I am unable to get disconnected groups to align on the same X axis.  There are many new options but attempts to resolve it using the options have failed.

QUESTION - Does anyone know how to get these groups to align as they did in v3.x?

This is old v.3 version and our desired state:
[image]

This is how it is rendering with v4.16.1 shows how the disconnected groups are aligned on the x axis. 
[image]